# what are the geometric relationships between $a^{2}+b^{2}=c^{2}+d^{2}$, and $a^{2}-ad+d^{2}=b^{2}+bc+c^{2}$?

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to solve this problem: Given positive real numbers $a,b,c,d$ that satisfy the equality: $a^{2}+b^{2}=c^{2}+d^{2}$, and $a^{2}-ad+d^{2}=b^{2}+bc+c^{2}$ find all possible values of the expression: $\frac{ab+cd}{ad+bc}$.

Note: there might be some errors in the calculation

I think I have a partial answer, but I am interested in getting the opinions of how you guys would solve this problem.

Here is my response:

The problem is as follows:

Given positive real numbers $a,b,c,d,$ that satisfy the following equalities:\[5mm]

\begin{equation}
a^{2}-ad+d^{2}=b^{2}+bc+c^{2},
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
a^{2}+b^{2}=c^{2}+d^{2},
\end{equation}

find all possible values of the expression:\[5mm]

\begin{equation}
\frac{ab+cd}{ad+bc}.
\end{equation}

\section*{Step 1}

Looking at the equality \begin{equation}
a^{2}+b^{2}=c^{2}+d^{2},
\end{equation}

we can see that this resembles two triangles, whose sum of squares are equal, where $a, b, c, d,$ may be equal or distinct however they cannot be equal to zero since they are elements of the set: $\mathbb R_{> 0}.$\[5mm]

This also follows, that the hypotenuse of one triangle is equal to the hypotenuse of the other one.\[5mm]

since \begin{equation}
a^{2}+b^{2}=c^{2}+d^{2},
\end{equation}

we can deduce that the squared of the hypotenuse $f^{2}, f \in \mathbb R_{> 0},$ is equal to:\[5mm]
\begin{equation}
f^{2} = a^{2}+b^{2},
\end{equation}

and \begin{equation}
f^{2} = c^{2}+d^{2},
\end{equation}

hence \begin{equation}
f = \sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}},
\end{equation}

and \begin{equation}
f = \sqrt{c^{2}+d^{2}}.
\end{equation}

this means that: \begin{equation}
 \sqrt{c^{2}+d^{2}} = \sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}.
\end{equation}\[5mm]

viewing this geometrically see the following diagram:\[5mm]

\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{two-triangles.jpg}\[5mm]

Imagine that we are in a unit circle, where $\sqrt{c^{2}+d^{2}}, \text{or} \sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}$
is the radius bounded between the angles $0<\alpha<\frac{\pi}{2},$ and  $0<\beta<\frac{\pi}{2},$ since $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb R_{> 0}.$\[5mm]

as the sine component gets larger, the cosine component gets smaller and vice versa however the length of the hypotenuse is invariant.\[5mm]

This gives us the following relationships:\[5mm]

\begin{equation}
a = (\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}})\cos{\alpha},
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
b = (\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}})\sin{\alpha},
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
c = (\sqrt{c^{2}+d^{2}})\cos{\beta},
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
d = (\sqrt{c^{2}+d^{2}})\sin{\beta},
\end{equation}

since \begin{equation}
 \sqrt{c^{2}+d^{2}} = \sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}
\end{equation}\[5mm]

we have that:\[5mm]

\begin{equation}
c = (\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}})\cos{\beta},
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
d = (\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}})\sin{\beta}.
\end{equation}

We can now insert these expressions into the equality: \begin{equation}
a^{2}-ad+d^{2}=b^{2}+bc+c^{2}.
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
a^{2}-ad+d^{2}&=b^{2}+bc+c^{2}\\
(a^{2}+b^{2})\cos^{2}{\alpha}-ad+(a^{2}+b^{2})\sin^{2}{\beta}&=(a^{2}+b^{2})\sin^{2}{\alpha}+bc+(a^{2}+b^{2})\cos^{2}{\beta}\\
(a^{2}+b^{2})(\cos^{2}{\alpha}-\sin^{2}{\alpha})-ad&=(a^{2}+b^{2})(\cos^{2}{\alpha}-\sin^{2}{\alpha})+bc\\
(a^{2}+b^{2})(\cos{2\alpha})-ad&=(a^{2}+b^{2})(\cos{2\beta})+bc\\
bc+ad&=(a^{2}+b^{2})(\cos{2\alpha})-(a^{2}+b^{2})(\cos{2\beta})\\
bc+ad&=(a^{2}+b^{2})(\cos{2\alpha}-\cos{2\beta}).\\
\end{align}

Answer (score -1):

*Hint:* The only positive real solutions are given by
$$
a=\frac{\sqrt{3}c + d}{2},\;
b=\frac{\sqrt{3}d - c}{2}
$$
with positive real numbers $c,d$ satisfying $c<\sqrt{3}d$. The quotient then can be computed easily. For example, with $c=d=1$, we have $a=\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2}$, $b=\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2}$, so that
$$
\frac{ab+cd}{ad+bc}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}.
$$
On the other hand, for $c=1,d=2$ we have
$$
\frac{ab+cd}{ad+bc}=\frac{3}{2}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{3}+4}{\sqrt{3}+3}.
$$
So there are infinitely many possible values for the quotient (take $c=1$ and any positive integer $d\ge 1$).